# Azure flexible server creation fails intermittenyl with the error " Operations on a server group in dropping state are not allowed"

Tags: azure

I am creating an Azure flexible server through terraform and the pipeline is in Azure devops.
The server creation fails intermittently with the error:

```
Server Name: "<server_name>"): polling after Create: Code="ServerGroupDropping" Message="Operations on a server group in dropping state are not allowed."
```

I have tried updating the azureRM version to >3.5, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/16622), but to no avail. It is also good to note here that the same code sometimes executes without any error.
Is this issue from Azure end or terraform. Also I don't actually see a workaround for the same but am open to suggestion.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

This error usually occurs when same Server name PostgreSQL was previously created.
Try using a different server name and redeploy.

Comment: I think this is bad design on behalf of the Azure Team. Using a different server name everytime you want to run your test scripts is bad design.

Comment: I did change the name but still giving me the same error :(

Comment: I get this error regardless if I've had an old PostgreSQL server with the same name or not. I got this error the first time I tried deploying an Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server. I've received this error while both deploying via terraform and deploying via the Azure portal, so this appears to be an Azure issue.

When deploying with terraform, I was deploying to 2 regions at the same time and neither region had a PostgreSQL instance deployed prior. One region (eastus) deployed fine, and the other region (westus) failed with this error.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Currently the issue persists on Azure's end.

Comment: When you create the PostgreSQL server with a 'fresh' name, a couple of times, the DNS does not refresh in Azure's internal database, even after a couple of days of the DB server being deleted. You can only raise a ticket with the Azure team and request them to remove the DNS record if it is of importance for you. For me , while testing, I just use different names to recreate the DB server.
PS : this issue is mainly due to my infrastructure testing and constant deletion and creation of the DB server.